iDrive backup system is interfering with Ubuntu -- how can I debug things?
I installed the iDrive backup system using these scripts on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. Everything seemed to go well, but the next time I rebooted, everything looked weird. Specifically, I identified the following issues:

the gnome extensions were disabled,
bluetooth and usb devices had stopped working,
nothing in the sound settings made sense (but probably that had something to do with bluetooth and usb malfunctioning).

The iDrive scripts do not use a standard .deb installation package unfortunately, so it seems plausible that the way their scripts load things, they will be interfering with the way everything else is loading, hence causing the above issues.
Is there a standard way to proceed, like, to find out where things went wrong? Or maybe to package the installation as a .deb? What would you suggest?
Thanks a lot in advance for your advice!

For now, what I did was, I changed the crontab so that the idrivecron service does not start at boot...
